# How many planets can be seen by the naked eye?

Tags: planet, solar-system, night-sky, naked-eye

I can see Venus and Mars, what about the others?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: this _is_ their research effort! :)

Comment: They've done enough research to know two fifths of the answer.

Comment: Everyone missed one: Earth!

Comment: You forgot the obvious: Earth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The faintest we can see is magnitude +6.5

Here are the apparent magnitudes of planets at their brightest, I've boldened the ones that fall within visible range:

**−4.92 planet Venus**

**−2.94 planet Jupiter**

**−2.94 planet Mars**

**−2.48 planet Mercury**

**−0.55 planet Saturn**

**+5.38 planet Uranus**

+6.64   dwarf planet Ceres

+7.67   planet Neptune

+13.65  dwarf planet Pluto

Other dwarf planets are generally fainter than this.

Source: **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude)**

Comment: Athough Mercury is bright, observing it by naked eye is pretty far from being easy :) Especially is you live far from equator. I live on 56 North and have seen Merqury only once.

Comment: @Heopps I agree since Mercury is so close to sun, it gets hidden under the sun's glare.

Comment: @Heopps the main problem is living that far *North* of the equator. It's easier to see it on the other hemisphere, due to where Mercury's aphelion lies.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Venus and Mars, one can easily see Mercury, Jupiter, and Saturn with the naked eye. Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn were known to the ancients. That's why they're called "planets" (which means wanderers) rather than stars. The outer planets were not discovered until the invention of the telescope.

Comment: But nevertheless, Uranus *is* bright enough to be seen with the naked eye if you know where to look.

Comment: @ProfRob Still Uranus is very hard to detect and it needs an eagle eye. I am not sure if Uranus is the farthest object in Solar system that you can see with naked eyes, so I asked in a separate post: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51131/is-uranus-the-farthest-object-in-solar-system-that-you-can-see-with-naked-eyes